# MySQLi and PDO in mariaDB with PHP7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, mariadb

I'm just beginning to learn some PHP/MySQL (and programming in general). I mostly use the documentation I find here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp
It systematically proposes methods using mySQLi or PDO extensions to access the DB in PHP, but I can't find if this is necessary if I use a MariaDB database, or if I have to add something in my MariaDB installation.

Comment: PHP uses the MySQL drivers to talk to MariaDB. Yes, you need them, no, you don’t need anything else

Comment: As far as I know PHP does not have specific drivers for MariaDB so, yes, you basically need to use the MySQL extensions available. (As about the tutorial you mention, it doesn't look as bad as the average tutorial but please don't use try/catch to echo exceptions, it's pointless and breaks many other things.)

Answer (score 0):

The esiest way to use mysql with PHP is the mysqli extension for PHP. You have to install the MySQLi extension in your PHP installation. On your mysql server you dont have to install any additional software. 
In your PHP you can access the datebase via some simple commands.

Look the following link for more documentation
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both PDO and mysqli to connect to MariaDB. I strongly recommend to chose PDO as it is easier for beginners and offers more options.

MariaDB is just a flavour of MySQL databases. It tries to retain compatibility with MySQL to a large extend. There are no separate drivers in PHP for MariaDB as the existing ones can be used.

To connect to MariaDB in PHP you use the same code as you would use with MySQL:

```
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8mb4", 'user', 'password', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you talk about "Methods" you must know that a Method is like a function but it always belongs to a Class. And then we talk about Object Oriented **PHP**

A function does not necessary belong to a class.It can exist outside it, Then we talk about Procedural **PHP**.

For you as a beginner I would propose to learn the Procedural version of the commands.
But you can as well learn the oo version.